# Can't access specific route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I return from a function with a view and a compact table:

```
$table = (new \Okipa\LaravelTable\Table)->model(Expense::class)->routes([
        'index'   => ['name' => 'admin.expenses.index'],
        'edit'    => ['name' => 'admin.expenses.edit'],
        'destroy' => ['name' => 'admin.expenses.destroy'],
    ])->tbodyTemplate('bootstrap.expenses.tbody')
        ->query(function($query) use($user){
            $query->select("expenses.*");
    //      $query->join('projects',"projects.id","=","expenses.project_id");
    //      $query->addSelect('projects.name as project');
           $query->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereNull('travel_id');
        });
return view('backend.expenses.index', compact('table'));
```

Laravel displays this error:

> Return value of Okipa\LaravelTable\Table::render() must be of the type string, object returned (View: /home/armand/Desktop/GSurvey/expenses/resources/views/vendor/laravel-table/bootstrap/table.blade.php)

The index blade is where it supposed to be and in the view I have just a simple line to display the table: `{{ $table }}`

Can anyone extend a helping hand, maybe I am missing something?

Thank you in advance,
Kind regards,
Armand Camner

Comment: Can you take look into `$table` and what it contains? Error message it must be a string but it is an object, so what type of an object it is. You can use a debugger and break point or just `dd($table);` to take a look.

Comment: I used dd($table) right before returning the view:

 Okipa\LaravelTable\Table {#1892 ▼
   Here lots of fields 
 }

Comment: Ok you have an `Okipa\LaravelTable\Table` object. Can you try manually render it. `dd($table->render());` ?

Comment: When I try to manual render it returns the same error { Return value of Okipa\LaravelTable\Table::render() must be of the type string, object returned }

Comment: Could it be that I have a problem with installing okipa: because when I run composer require okipa/laravel-table I get Problem 1
    - okipa/laravel-table[4.0.0, ..., 4.0.4] require illuminate/support ^7.0||^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires okipa/laravel-table ^4.0 -> satisfiable by okipa/laravel-table[4.0.0, ..., 4.0.4].

Comment: What is your Laravel version and which version of `okipa/laravel-table` are you trying to use?

Comment: In composer I have: "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
        "okipa/laravel-table": "^1.0",

Comment: Package's README says you must use version ^2.0 for Laravel 6.x : https://github.com/Okipa/laravel-table/blob/36b146485303a8e0f94ef7653402e73ed7126eae/README.md?plain=1#L37 I think you should change it this way and check out 2.0 documentation.